# Sending data from MS Access to a html form

Tags: html, ms-access, vba

I would like to send data to a html form from MS Access.

I would like to do something like this:

`http://webaddress/form.php?what=something`

from Visual Basic. Can I do this?

Comment: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/msaccess/article.php/3513061

Comment: Yes, but that's almost certainly not what you mean. Time for some tutorials and then you can ask better questions, loads of them about on PHP, windows, or linux based and even with access.

Comment: Dear Robert! Thank you for the quick answer. Running a dos command is an option, but is there a better way? 
Dear Tony: I need to send data from a MS Access database to a local php form. What would be a better question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a stab and assume that you are *not* hosting pages from your MS-Access Database.

What you need to do is reference the Microsoft Web Browser Control in your project, and pass the URL with the parameters to that control. You can then monitor the control to see if the server sent you error codes, and what messages came from the server.

Here's a link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304643

Comment: Thank you. I am not hosting pages with MS-Access. Is it possible to do it without the MS Web Browser Control? I would like to send some data while I do a scheduled run of a VB function inside MS-Access.